# Three insert statements into three tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following insert statements:

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO `firm`(name, VAT, active) VALUES ('$name', '$VAT', '$active')"; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `area`(name, hub_name, fk_hub_id) VALUES ('$areaname',(SELECT `name` from hub WHERE name = '$hub_name'), (SELECT `id` from hub WHERE name = '$hub_name'))";

$sql ="INSERT INTO 'contactdetails'
        (fk_firm_id,
         address_physical_line_1,
         address_physical_line_2,
         address_physical_line_3,
         address_physical_line_4,
         address_physical_line_5,
         address_physical_line_6,
         address_physical_line_7,
         address_physical_code,
         address_postal_line_1,
         address_postal_line_2,
         address_postal_line_3,
         address_postal_line_4,
         address_postal_line_5,
         address_postal_line_6,
         address_postal_line_7,
         address_postal_code,
         fax_1,
         fax_2,
         phone_1,
         phone_2,
         phone_3,
         phone_4)
VALUES      ( (SELECT `id`
           FROM   firm
           WHERE  name = '$name'),
          '$address_physical_line_1',
          '$address_physical_line_2',
          '$address_physical_line_3',
          '$address_physical_line_4',
          '$address_physical_line_5',
          '$address_physical_line_6',
          '$address_physical_line_7',
          '$address_physical_code',
          '$address_postal_line_1',
          '$address_postal_line_2',
          '$address_postal_line_3',
          '$address_postal_line_4',
          '$address_postal_line_5',
          '$address_postal_line_6',
          '$address_postal_line_7',
          '$address_postal_code',
          '$fax_1',
          '$fax_2',
          '$phone_1',
          '$phone_2',
          '$phone_3',
          '$phone_4')  ";
```

Do i have to use transactional statement to run these three queries.  I have never worked with transactional statements.  The one statement is depending on values of the other ones.

Comment: Why on earth do you have each address line in separate column? Can't you just put some separator there, newline, | or something?

Comment: use multi-query from mysql to execute all at once. its queued execution.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has `AUTO_COMMIT` set to true by default. This means that every query in your script will be executed before the one right after.

This allows you to do something like :

```
// Here I admit that the table is empty, with an auto-incremented id.
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', 'First');
INSERT INTO test ('', SELECT value FROM test WHERE id = "1");
```

Here, you will insert a first row with `id=1, value="First"` and then `id=2, value="First"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand your question but *if* you need to perform several SQL requests guaranteeing they are either *all* done or *none* done, you have to explicitly create and commit a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT ...
INSERT ...
INSERT ...

-- All is ready, apply "all at once"
COMMIT
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

---

Just to be clear (?), from *inside* your transaction, all the SQL statements appear to be executed "one by one as usual". But from *outside* world (other transactions/connections to you SQL server) no change would appear until you `COMMIT` your transaction -- and then *all* changes will appear "all at once".